# How can I detach element from a sidebar and insert somewhere else?

Tags: jquery

I used this snippet to remove content from a sidebar and then add in my header:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
  if($(window).width() < 1000 ){
    $(".red").detach().insertBefore(".blue");
  }
  else{
   $("#mobile_sidebar").detach().insertAfter("div#templatic_text-16"); 
  }
     });
});
```

```css
.red{
  background: red;
}
.green{
  background: green;
}
.blue{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<div class="main_container">
<p>This is the paragraph</p>
  <a href="#">This is a link text</a>

</div>
<div class="red">
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, dicta modi ratione sit cupiditate qui tempore soluta, optio consequatur in vero. Qui deleniti voluptates quod, distinctio aperiam provident tempore facere.</h1>
</div>
<div class="green">
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, dicta modi ratione sit cupiditate qui tempore soluta, optio consequatur in vero. Qui deleniti voluptates quod, distinctio aperiam provident tempore facere.</h1>
</div>
<div class="blue">
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, dicta modi ratione sit cupiditate qui tempore soluta, optio consequatur in vero. Qui deleniti voluptates quod, distinctio aperiam provident tempore facere.</h1>
</div>
```

Right now on desktop version where I can resize the screen, I see that if I scale the page down to 600px it works. But I increase the size of the screen again, the content of the side bar does not go back to normal.

Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on('resize', function(event){
    if($(window).width() < 1000 ){
      $(".red").detach().insertBefore(".blue");
    }
    else{
       $(".red").detach().insertBefore(".green"); 
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.red{
  background: red;
}
.green{
  background: green;
}
.blue{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<div class="main_container">
<p>This is the paragraph</p>
  <a href="#">This is a link text</a>

</div>
<div class="red">
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, dicta modi ratione sit cupiditate qui tempore soluta, optio consequatur in vero. Qui deleniti voluptates quod, distinctio aperiam provident tempore facere.</h1>
</div>
<div class="green">
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, dicta modi ratione sit cupiditate qui tempore soluta, optio consequatur in vero. Qui deleniti voluptates quod, distinctio aperiam provident tempore facere.</h1>
</div>
<div class="blue">
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, dicta modi ratione sit cupiditate qui tempore soluta, optio consequatur in vero. Qui deleniti voluptates quod, distinctio aperiam provident tempore facere.</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I suppose that this is the following html that javascript gets applied:

```
<div id="mobile_sidebar">Hello</div>
<!-- some html -->
<div class="home_page_banner">Java</div>
<!-- some html -->
<div id="templatic_text-16"></div>
```

Then you should try by changing the `div#templatic_text-16` with `#templatic_text-16` resulting to this javascript:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 600){
    console.log("small");
        $("#mobile_sidebar").detach().insertBefore(".home_page_banner"); 
    }
    else{
    console.log("big");
        $("#mobile_sidebar").detach().insertAfter("#templatic_text-16"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer does not really differ from the code I have.
IF you load my snippet on a big screen and then resize you will see that at some pont the red paragraph move down after the green. But if you scale the page up again, the red paragraph does  not go back its default position.

Comment: I did not see your snippet when I was posting perhaps we posted the same time. Also the question has not been edited then.